# I want to print out some array's text on my browser <p> element here's my code,

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
<body>

<p id="id"></p>

<script>
    function StringBuilder() {
        this._Buffer = [];

        StringBuilder.prototype = {

            Constructor: StringBuilder,

            add: function (str) {
                this._Buffer.push(str);
            },

            toString: function () {
                return this._Buffer.join('');
            }
        }
    }

    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.add = "obber";
    sb.add = "stadspolizie";

    var id = document.getElementById("id");
    id.innerText = sb.toString();


</script>

</body>
<!-- all I see on the screen is [onject Object] how can I display the text there? -->
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you are using `add` like a `setter` when it should be used as a `method` (function call). In other words:

**This:**

```
sb.add = "obber";
```

**Should be:**

```
sb.add("obber");
```

After that, you will notice that the `add` method is `undefined` if you try to run that. That is because you need to move the prototypical methods outside of the constructor.

**Final example:**

```js
function StringBuilder() {
  this._Buffer = [];
}

StringBuilder.prototype = {
  Constructor: StringBuilder,
  add: function(str) {
    this._Buffer.push(str);
  },
  toString: function() {
    return this._Buffer.join('');
  }
};

var sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.add("obber");
sb.add("stadspolizie");

var id = document.getElementById("id");
id.innerText = sb.toString();
```

```html
<p id="id"></p>
```